# ¿Cómo trazar una línea horizontal desde una fecha específica en un gráfico de velas japonesas usando MatPlotLibFinance en Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, gráficas, visualización-de-datos

Recientemente me puse la tarea de desarrollar un pequeño código en `Python3` que grafique los **precios OHLC** almacenados en una dataframe y que además resalte en dicho gráfico una línea horizontal para un precio específico. Para dicho trabajo se hizo uso de la librería [MatPlotLibFinance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) y de la muy famosa librería [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/)

La dataframe usada (llamada en este caso `df_trading_pair_date_time_index`) fue la siguiente:

```
                      Open   High    Low  Close   Volume                End Date
Start Date                                                                      
2022-09-25 07:15:00  5.473  5.495  5.473  5.490  11186.8 2022-09-25 07:17:59.999
2022-09-25 07:18:00  5.491  5.522  5.491  5.517  14063.3 2022-09-25 07:20:59.999
2022-09-25 07:21:00  5.518  5.518  5.499  5.508   5728.8 2022-09-25 07:23:59.999
2022-09-25 07:24:00  5.508  5.511  5.496  5.501   3691.7 2022-09-25 07:26:59.999
2022-09-25 07:27:00  5.499  5.505  5.498  5.500   1146.3 2022-09-25 07:29:59.999
2022-09-25 07:30:00  5.498  5.501  5.491  5.491   2743.0 2022-09-25 07:32:59.999
2022-09-25 07:33:00  5.490  5.494  5.489  5.492   1670.0 2022-09-25 07:35:59.999
2022-09-25 07:36:00  5.494  5.497  5.492  5.496   1341.0 2022-09-25 07:38:59.999
2022-09-25 07:39:00  5.500  5.502  5.491  5.492   1750.0 2022-09-25 07:41:59.999
2022-09-25 07:42:00  5.490  5.492  5.477  5.477   4139.7 2022-09-25 07:44:59.999
2022-09-25 07:45:00  5.476  5.484  5.473  5.484   2292.4 2022-09-25 07:47:59.999
2022-09-25 07:48:00  5.483  5.492  5.480  5.491   2312.6 2022-09-25 07:50:59.999
2022-09-25 07:51:00  5.492  5.500  5.491  5.499   2372.2 2022-09-25 07:53:59.999
2022-09-25 07:54:00  5.500  5.505  5.498  5.502   2511.2 2022-09-25 07:56:59.999
2022-09-25 07:57:00  5.502  5.504  5.500  5.500   1696.4 2022-09-25 07:59:59.999
2022-09-25 08:00:00  5.500  5.507  5.499  5.507   1742.7 2022-09-25 08:02:59.999
2022-09-25 08:03:00  5.506  5.512  5.502  5.512   1276.9 2022-09-25 08:05:59.999
2022-09-25 08:06:00  5.511  5.512  5.505  5.508   3885.8 2022-09-25 08:08:59.999
2022-09-25 08:09:00  5.507  5.509  5.503  5.507   1209.7 2022-09-25 08:11:59.999
2022-09-25 08:12:00  5.507  5.510  5.504  5.510   1270.1 2022-09-25 08:14:59.999
```

Los tipos de datos que contienen las columnas de la `df_trading_pair_date_time_index` al ejecutar `df_trading_pair_date_time_index.dtypes` son los siguientes:

```
Open               float64
High               float64
Low                float64
Close              float64
Volume             float64
End Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Y al ejecutar `df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index.dtype`, el tipo de dato de la columna índice es el siguiente (es el mismo de la columna `End Date`):

```
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Finalmente, el código encargado de graficar dichos datos y resaltar una línea horizontal para un precio específico, fue el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Plotting
# Create my own `marketcolors` style:
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
# Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh', 'dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

# Plot it
trading_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                    figratio=(10, 6),
                    type="candle",
                    style=s,
                    tight_layout=True,
                    datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                    ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                    returnfig=True,
                    show_nontrading=True,
                    hlines=dict(hlines=[df_trading_pair_date_time_index['Open'].iat[-5]],colors=['#06FF44'],linestyle='-.', linewidths=3)
                    )
# Add Title
symbol = trading_pair.replace("BUSD","")+"/"+"BUSD"
axlist[0].set_title(f"{symbol} - 3m", fontsize=25, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy')

# Find which times should be shown every 6 minutes starting at the last row of the df
x_axis_minutes = []
for i in range (1,len(df_trading_pair_date_time_index),2):
    x_axis_minutes.append(df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index[-i].minute)

# Set the main "ticks" to show at the x axis
axlist[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=x_axis_minutes))

# Set the x axis label
axlist[0].set_xlabel('Zona Horaria UTC')

trading_plot.savefig('asdf.png',dpi=600, bbox_inches = "tight")
```

> *Nota: Lo que resalta la línea horizontal en la gráfica en sí es el*
> *parámetro* `hlines`
> usado dentro del método `.plot()`

El cual retornó la siguiente gráfica:

[image: gráfica inicial]

Sin embargo, me interesa aprender cómo se puede especificar la ***fecha de inicio*** desde la que se trazaría la línea horizontal de la figura de arriba, para que esta línea horizontal no recorra todo el gráfico sino solamente aquellos valores posteriores a la fecha de inicio, es decir, un gráfico como el siguiente:

[image: gráfico deseado]

Sí no es mucha molestia, también quisiera saber cómo se podría agregar un pequeño texto anclado a dicha línea horizontal como se muestra en la imagen.

Agradezco a cualquiera que me ayude a resolver mi situación.

Comment: Enhotabuena por una pregunta muy completa y detallada. Solo falta saber cómo está definido `df_trading_pair` para que tu código sea ejecutable y por tanto replicable. O bien si se puede evitar utilizar esa variable y en cambio obtener lo que se necesita para dibujar la línea horizontal directamente del dataframe `df_trading_pair_date_time_index`

Comment: Mil disculpas, no me había fijado en ese detallle, ya re acomodé el código para que no haga uso de la variable `df_trading_pair` sino de la variable `df_trading_pair_date_time_index` @abulafia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que se me ocurre es no utilizar el parámetro `hlines` de  mplfinance, sino utilizar directamente primitivas de matplotlib como `hlines` y `text`.

Para que esto funcione necesitamos extraer las fechas de inicio y fin de la línea. Por ejemplo usaré como fecha de inicio `"2022-09-25 07:45:00"` y como fecha de fin la última del dataframe:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime("2022-09-25 07:45:00")
last_date = pd.to_datetime(df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index[-1])
```

La altura a la que hay que dibujar la línea es el precio "Open" de la fecha de inicio, el cual extraemos así:

```
support_price = df_trading_pair_date_time_index.loc[start_date, "Open"]
```

Y ahora ya tenemos lo que necesitamos para pintar la línea:

```
axlist[0].hlines(support_price, xmin=start_date, xmax=last_date, 
                 color="#06FF44", linestyle="-.", linewidth=3)
```

Para añadir el texto podemos usar como coordenadas la fecha final del gráfico y la altura de la hline, y especificar para el texto alineación vertical "top" (para que salga debajo de esa línea) y alineación horizontal "right" (para que salga a la izquierda de la fecha final). El problema es que no hay forma de especificar un "padding" alrededor del texto, por lo que este sale pegado a la línea de soporte. Para separarlo un poco hay que restar una cantidad a la coordenada, pero la cantidad a restar depende bastante de cada gráfica (de la separación entre los valores en el eje y). Para este caso he encontrado por ensayo y error el valor 0.001. Entonces:

```
axlist[0].text(x=last_date, y=support_price-0.001, s="Precio Soporte", 
               ha="right", va="top", fontsize="14", color="#06FF44")
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Código completo (reproducible):

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import io

data="""
                      Open   High    Low  Close   Volume                End Date
Start Date                                                                      
2022-09-25 07:15:00  5.473  5.495  5.473  5.490  11186.8  2022-09-25 07:17:59.999
2022-09-25 07:18:00  5.491  5.522  5.491  5.517  14063.3  2022-09-25 07:20:59.999
2022-09-25 07:21:00  5.518  5.518  5.499  5.508   5728.8  2022-09-25 07:23:59.999
2022-09-25 07:24:00  5.508  5.511  5.496  5.501   3691.7  2022-09-25 07:26:59.999
2022-09-25 07:27:00  5.499  5.505  5.498  5.500   1146.3  2022-09-25 07:29:59.999
2022-09-25 07:30:00  5.498  5.501  5.491  5.491   2743.0  2022-09-25 07:32:59.999
2022-09-25 07:33:00  5.490  5.494  5.489  5.492   1670.0  2022-09-25 07:35:59.999
2022-09-25 07:36:00  5.494  5.497  5.492  5.496   1341.0  2022-09-25 07:38:59.999
2022-09-25 07:39:00  5.500  5.502  5.491  5.492   1750.0  2022-09-25 07:41:59.999
2022-09-25 07:42:00  5.490  5.492  5.477  5.477   4139.7  2022-09-25 07:44:59.999
2022-09-25 07:45:00  5.476  5.484  5.473  5.484   2292.4  2022-09-25 07:47:59.999
2022-09-25 07:48:00  5.483  5.492  5.480  5.491   2312.6  2022-09-25 07:50:59.999
2022-09-25 07:51:00  5.492  5.500  5.491  5.499   2372.2  2022-09-25 07:53:59.999
2022-09-25 07:54:00  5.500  5.505  5.498  5.502   2511.2  2022-09-25 07:56:59.999
2022-09-25 07:57:00  5.502  5.504  5.500  5.500   1696.4  2022-09-25 07:59:59.999
2022-09-25 08:00:00  5.500  5.507  5.499  5.507   1742.7  2022-09-25 08:02:59.999
2022-09-25 08:03:00  5.506  5.512  5.502  5.512   1276.9  2022-09-25 08:05:59.999
2022-09-25 08:06:00  5.511  5.512  5.505  5.508   3885.8  2022-09-25 08:08:59.999
2022-09-25 08:09:00  5.507  5.509  5.503  5.507   1209.7  2022-09-25 08:11:59.999
2022-09-25 08:12:00  5.507  5.510  5.504  5.510   1270.1  2022-09-25 08:14:59.999
"""

df_trading_pair_date_time_index = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), sep=r"\s\s+", parse_dates=["Start Date", "End Date"])

# Plotting
# Create my own `marketcolors` style:
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
# Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh', 'dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

# Plot it
trading_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                    figratio=(10, 6),
                    type="candle",
                    style=s,
                    tight_layout=True,
                    datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                    ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                    returnfig=True,
                    show_nontrading=True,
                    )

# Plot and label support price
start_date = pd.to_datetime("2022-09-25 07:45:00")
last_date = pd.to_datetime(df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index[-1])
support_price = df_trading_pair_date_time_index.loc[start_date, "Open"]

axlist[0].hlines(support_price, xmin=start_date, xmax=last_date, 
                 color="#06FF44", linestyle="-.", linewidth=3)
axlist[0].text(x=last_date, y=support_price-0.001, s="Precio Soporte", 
               ha="right", va="top", fontsize="14", color="#06FF44")  

# Add Title
symbol = "APE/BUSD"
axlist[0].set_title(f"{symbol} - 3m", fontsize=25, style='italic')

# Find which times should be shown every 6 minutes starting at the last row of the df
x_axis_minutes = []
for i in range (1,len(df_trading_pair_date_time_index),2):
    x_axis_minutes.append(df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index[-i].minute)

# Set the main "ticks" to show at the x axis
axlist[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=x_axis_minutes))

# Set the x axis label
axlist[0].set_xlabel('Zona Horaria UTC')
```

### Detalle adicional

Si te parece (como a mi) que queda un poco feo que la línea se corte antes de llegar al extremo de la gráfica, puedes extenderla artificalmente sumándole un `timedelta()`. En este caso llevarla cinco minutos más allá es suficiente. Pero no pasa nada si "te pasas" porque lo que se salga de la gráfica no se pinta:

```
import datetime

...

axlist[0].hlines(y=support_price, xmin=start_date, 
                 xmax=last_date+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5), 
                 color="#06FF44", linestyle="-.", linewidth=2)
```

y ahora se ve así:

[image: Resultado mejorado]

Comment: WOW, ¡Muchísimas gracias! Quedé atónito.

Comment: No hay de qué. Revisa la ampliación que he añadido